# Xcode Continuous Integration: detecting the CI environment during a post-action script

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-server

I am looking to run scripts in the post-action phase of my build, but only when building in the Xcode CI environment.  Are there any environment variables or other ways to detect that the build is taking place as part of Xcode CI?

Note: this is a [cross-post from the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/908316#908316).

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
if [[ "$USER" == "_teamsserver" ]]
then
    # do something
else
    # do something else
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For CI you should use Shared scheme, and you can add script to the scheme after build phase.

Answer (score 0):

it's quiet hard to detect if you are building from CI. But i use a trick to do that : I ask to my bot to archive the app and I added post-action on the archive part of my scheme.

Is it good for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You could take an alternative approach where you could use different build configuration and just qualify the script. Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084094/2415693 for a similar question.