# Possible to execute script when app built by CI bot but not by dev?

Tags: xcode

I would like to run a perl script when my app is being built a a CI machine bot, but I do not want the script to be run if the app is being built manually when being built on a dev machine.

Is there any way of achieving this other than duplicating the targets and having one target containing a script build phase and another target not containing the script build phase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posted this answer to a similar question at:
[Xcode Continuous Integration: detecting the CI environment during a post-action script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499842/xcode-continuous-integration-detecting-the-ci-environment-during-a-post-action/21180899#21180899)

Here it is, if it helps:

```
if [[ "$USER" == "_teamsserver" ]]
then
    # do something
else
    # do something else
fi
```

[Since your question is tagged as 'Xcode', this solution is particular to Xcode.  It won't work for just any C.I. system.]

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different build configurations where one would be just the copy of the other. Then qualify the run script to use the configuration that the CI scheme will use.

E.g.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "CI_Release" ]; then
  echo Run your perl script here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use a completely separate scheme for your Xcode Bot.  One of the benefits is the ability to easily run a different set of scripts during various stages of the build process.